# How to avoid errors in trigonometry functions in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a curson in my stored procedure

```
 SELECT a.id, a.full_address, me.answer medid, me.name NAME, a.nlat, a.nlong, a.parent_table
      FROM   example_table_1 a,
             (SELECT pnradius         AS radius,
                     111.045          AS distance_unit,
                     57.2957795       AS rad2deg,
                     0.01745329251994 AS deg2rad
              FROM   dual) geo,
             example_table me
      WHERE  a.nlat BETWEEN pnlatitude - (geo.radius / geo.distance_unit) AND
             pnlatitude + (geo.radius / geo.distance_unit)
      AND    a.nlong BETWEEN pnlongitude - (geo.radius / (geo.distance_unit * cos(deg2rad * (pnlatitude)))) AND
             pnlongitude + (geo.radius / (geo.distance_unit * cos(deg2rad * (pnlatitude))))
      AND    geo.distance_unit * rad2deg *
             (acos(cos(deg2rad * (pnlatitude)) * cos(deg2rad * (a.nlat)) * cos(deg2rad * (pnlongitude - a.nlong)) +
                    sin(deg2rad * (pnlatitude)) * sin(deg2rad * (a.nlat)))) < pnradius
      AND    a.parent_id = me.answer
      AND    a.parent_table = 'example_table'
```

pnlatitude and pnlongiture are paramenters of procedure. 
In most cases this cursor works great. But sometimes in some areas in Russia this cursor cause this error:

[image]

I understand what is going on here, but I can't track where does it happen. I can adjust deg2rad value and it helps, but then this error will appear with other coordinates.

Is it possible to reduce the value of trigonometry function paramentr to 1 when it is more than 1?

Comment: An ORA-01428 error is "argument out of range". The problem appears to be in the ACOS function call.

Comment: Instead of `57.2957795` and `0.01745329251994` try `180/ACOS(-1)` and `ACOS(-1)/180`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LEAST` function to ensure you don't pass an argument greater than 1 to `ACOS`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.full_address, me.answer medid, me.name NAME, a.nlat, a.nlong, a.parent_table
  FROM example_table_1 a,
       (SELECT pnradius         AS radius,
               111.045          AS distance_unit,
               57.2957795       AS rad2deg,
               0.01745329251994 AS deg2rad
          FROM dual) geo,
       example_table me
  WHERE a.nlat BETWEEN pnlatitude - (geo.radius / geo.distance_unit)
                   AND pnlatitude + (geo.radius / geo.distance_unit) 
    AND a.nlong BETWEEN pnlongitude - (geo.radius / (geo.distance_unit * cos(deg2rad * (pnlatitude))))
                    AND pnlongitude + (geo.radius / (geo.distance_unit * cos(deg2rad * (pnlatitude))))
    AND geo.distance_unit * rad2deg *
        (acos(LEAST(cos(deg2rad * (pnlatitude)) * cos(deg2rad * (a.nlat)) * cos(deg2rad * (pnlongitude - a.nlong)) +
        sin(deg2rad * (pnlatitude)) * sin(deg2rad * (a.nlat)), 1))) < pnradius
    AND a.parent_id = me.answer
    AND a.parent_table = 'example_table'
```

This is the same as your original with a `LEAST(big-long-calc, 1)` added inside the `ACOS` call. Hopefully I counted the parentheses right - if not, adjust as necessary. :-)

Best of luck.